# Convert Text to Number in MySQL to allow arithmetic operators

Tags: mysql, arithmetic-expressions

I'm dealing with some crappy datasources (the data is being stored on another database and pushed into my database as text even though it should be stored as integer... this isn't always the case, but it is happening frequently due to the way the datasource was set up and unfortunately I can't just change the datasource).

I would like to perform some simple functions on this data, but due to many of the values being stored as text, the resulting value from the arithmetic operator is zero.

Is there a way I can convert the string to a number within my SQL query to allow these functions to return the value of the sum of the columns rather than zeros:

SELECT
  `closeout_sl_dataform`.`OFS_ID` AS `OFS`,
  ((`closeout_sl_dataform`.`PO1_FE_HRS_CLOSEOUT_SL` + `closeout_sl_dataform`.`PO2_FE_HRS_CLOSEOUT_SL`) + `closeout_sl_dataform`.`PO3_FE_HRS_CLOSEOUT_SL`) AS `TOTAL_FE_HOURS`,
  ((`closeout_sl_dataform`.`PO1_FE_COST_CLOSEOUT_SL_USD` + `closeout_sl_dataform`.`PO2_FE_COST_CLOSEOUT_SL_USD`) + `closeout_sl_dataform`.`PO3_FE_COST_CLOSEOUT_SL_USD`) AS `TOTAL_FE_COST`,
  ((`closeout_sl_dataform`.`PO1_CRAFT_COST_CLOSEOUT_SL_USD` + `closeout_sl_dataform`.`PO2_CRAFT_COST_CLOSEOUT_SL_USD`) + `closeout_sl_dataform`.`PO3_CRAFT_COST_CLOSEOUT_SL_USD`) AS `TOTAL_CRAFT_COST`,
  `closeout_sl_dataform`.`CRANE` AS `TOTAL_CRANE`,
  `closeout_sl_dataform`.`SCAFFOLDING` AS `TOTAL_SCAFF`,
  `closeout_sl_dataform`.`PO1_TOTAL_COST_CLOSEOUT_SL` AS `TOTAL_PO1`,
  `closeout_sl_dataform`.`PO2_TOTAL_COST_CLOSEOUT_SL` AS `TOTAL_PO2`,
  `closeout_sl_dataform`.`PO3_TOTAL_COST_CLOSEOUT_SL` AS `TOTAL_PO3`,
  ((`closeout_sl_dataform`.`PO1_TOTAL_COST_CLOSEOUT_SL` + `closeout_sl_dataform`.`PO2_TOTAL_COST_CLOSEOUT_SL`) + `closeout_sl_dataform`.`PO3_TOTAL_COST_CLOSEOUT_SL`) AS `SUMPO123`
FROM `closeout_sl_dataform`

As it is now, `TOTAL_FE_HOURS` is resulting in a value of 0 most of the time due to the values in the expression being text type instead of integer. My tables all have column values of VARCHAR in order to accept the values whether they were set up as integer or numeric in the original datasource.

I appreciate the help! I'm very much a novice at SQL and while I'm sure this is probably trivial, I'm stumbling around trying to figure it out on my own.

Comment: What is holding you back to initiate a shadow database designed by you based on the input of these text things?

Comment: I've got two weeks left in my current position before taking on a new role with the company, was hoping for a quick fix that would allow me to tackle my growing pile of 'to do' before moving on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the snippet of code you're going to need to add to each of your string-to-number fields is `CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,'-',-1),UNSIGNED INTEGER)`. For instance:

```
CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(IFNULL(closeout_sl_dataform.PO1_FE_HRS_CLOSEOUT_SL,0),',',''),'$','') AS DECIMAL(10,2)) +  
CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(IFNULL(closeout_sl_dataform.PO2_FE_HRS_CLOSEOUT_SL,0),',',''),'$','') AS DECIMAL(10,2)) +  
CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(IFNULL(closeout_sl_dataform.PO3_FE_HRS_CLOSEOUT_SL,0),',',''),'$','') AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS TOTAL_FE_HOURS
```

Comment: Thanks stitzelj, will symbols make a difference? Right now the values in the columns are formatted as $xx,xxx.

Comment: Yes, it will. I've edited my answer above with the updated syntax.